# How to swap HTML elements in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am using classic Javascript for DOM scripting, i have a set of DIV's in a container DIV.
On click event of child DIV's, i want that the child DIV which has caused event to be swaped with the DIV above it..
my code goes here..

```
 <div id="container">
        <div onclick="swapDiv(event);">1</div>
        <div onclick="swapDiv(event);">2</div>
        <div onclick="swapDiv(event);">3</div>
 </div>
```

if DIV 2 has been clicked it should be swap with DIV 1

Comment: And if div 1 is clicked?

Comment: if div is 1 then no swapping...

Comment: swap just the contents, or the entire elements?

Comment: if you ever fancy using jQuery: [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This code will do what you want (if you want to swap the selected with the first child element). In case you want something else you need to be more precise.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function swapDiv(event, elem) {
    elem.parentNode.insertBefore(elem, elem.parentNode.firstChild);
  }
</script>


<div id="container">
  <div onclick="swapDiv(event,this);">1</div>
  <div onclick="swapDiv(event,this);">2</div>
  <div onclick="swapDiv(event,this);">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah that's about the same as what I thought, but he doesn't always want to put it first, he wants to put it above the div before it. So the `previousSibling`. It's a good start for him tho.

Comment: in this code, when you click on DIV 3, the DIV 3 swap's with DIV 1 instead of DIV 2..

Comment: glad, you were able to modify it to your case

Answer (score 19):

An element's `parentNode` property gives you its parent node. Elements have an `insertBefore` function that inserts an element before another reference element (moving it if it's already elsewhere in the tree). And nodes have a `previousSibling` that gives you the previous sibling node (which may or may not be an element). So:

```javascript
function swapDiv(elm) {
    var previous = findPrevious(elm);
    if (previous) {
        elm.parentNode.insertBefore(elm, previous);
    }
}
```

...where `findPrevious` looks like this:

```
function findPrevious(elm) {
   do {
       elm = elm.previousSibling;
   } while (elm && elm.nodeType != 1);
   return elm;
}
```

...where your `onclick` attributes should be:

```
onclick="swapDiv(this);"
```

...although you may want to look into DOM2 event hooking instead (`addEventListener`, or `attachEvent` on IE).

Slightly OT, but can I recommend using any of the several libraries available that make your life easier, such as [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). In fact, there was an error in an earlier version of this because it had been *that* long since I'd dealt with the DOM directly. :-)

Comment: This is pretty much what's already been answered, but I'm voting you up because you give a good complete answer.

Comment: Just what I was looking for

Answer (score 12):

Swap any nodes, not siblings, not adjecent siblings, no temp nodes, no cloning, no jquery... IE9+

```
function swapNodes(n1, n2) {

    var p1 = n1.parentNode;
    var p2 = n2.parentNode;
    var i1, i2;

    if ( !p1 || !p2 || p1.isEqualNode(n2) || p2.isEqualNode(n1) ) return;

    for (var i = 0; i < p1.children.length; i++) {
        if (p1.children[i].isEqualNode(n1)) {
            i1 = i;
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < p2.children.length; i++) {
        if (p2.children[i].isEqualNode(n2)) {
            i2 = i;
        }
    }

    if ( p1.isEqualNode(p2) && i1 < i2 ) {
        i2++;
    }
    p1.insertBefore(n2, p1.children[i1]);
    p2.insertBefore(n1, p2.children[i2]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful. How about [`isSameNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/isSameNode) (or `===`) instead of `isEqualNode` (in all places)?

Answer (score 6):

This works for siblings, should work for any two nodes:

```
function swapElements(el1, el2) {
    let prev1 = el1.previousSibling;
    let prev2 = el2.previousSibling;

    prev1.after(el2);
    prev2.after(el1);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure it would work if one of these element has no previous sibling because no whitespace between the elements

Answer (score 2):

From the sounds of it you basically just want to swap the div with the div before it, ergo with the `previousSibling`. You could maybe look at doing an `insertBefore` but instead of creating a new element use the existing one. I'm not sure what happens to the attached events tho, if they will be copied over correctly.

Comment: `previousSibling` will usually be a whitespace Text node (except on IE).

Comment: true, but then just test the nodeType, and if it's 3 get the `previousSibling` (if available) until you found one of nodeType 1. That's not too difficult.

Answer (score 2):

In principle you just `insertBefore` your clicked element before its previous element sibling. However, the presence of whitespace Text nodes makes that more annoying than it should be in traditional scripting. The [Element Traversal API](http://www.w3.org/TR/ElementTraversal/) will make this easier, but until it is more widely supported in browsers, helper functions are necessary, eg.:

```
<div id="container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Bind event to each line div
    //
    var div= firstElementChild(document.getElementById('container'));
    while (div!==null) {
        div.onclick= swapWithPreviousElement;
        div= nextElementSibling(div);
    }

    // Move element before its previous element sibling
    //
    function swapWithPreviousElement() {
        var previous= previousElementSibling(this);
        if (previous!==null)
            this.parentNode.insertBefore(this, previous);
    }


    // We've used some Element Traversal API methods but some
    // browsers don't support them yet. Provide wrapper functions
    // for compatibility.
    //
    function previousElementSibling(element) {
        if ('previousElementSibling' in element)
            return element.previousElementSibling;
        do
            element= element.previousSibling;
        while (element!==null && element.nodeType!==1);
        return element;
    }
    function nextElementSibling(element) {
        if ('nextElementSibling' in element)
            return element.nextElementSibling;
        do
            element= element.nextSibling;
        while (element!==null && element.nodeType!==1);
        return element;
    }
    function firstElementChild(element) {
        if ('firstElementChild' in element)
            return element.firstElementChild;
        var child= element.firstChild;
        while (child!==null && child.nodeType!==1)
            child= child.nextSibling;
        return child;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can swap a DOM element with its previous sibling like that:

```js
el.parentNode.insertBefore(el, el.previousElementSibling);
```